# Image under a position:absolute; DIV background image?

Tags: css, position, z-index, absolute

I've searched everywhere, and I just can't find out the answer to this.

So I have a DIV in my style sheet, that is positioned absolute and with a background image.

Inside that DIV, I have an  that I want to appear UNDER the DIV background.

I've tried z-index but it dosn't seem to work!? Is it something to to with the absolute position on my DIV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you do, you CANNOT make child elements appear BELOW their parent's background (see about [stacking contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers) for more info.) You need to modify your DOM so that the second element is taken outside of the DIV having a background to be shown in front of that element.

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a rookie mistake - I completely forgot. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Put the image div before the your absolute positioned one. That should put it under the other div. You could also

```
position: absolute
```

the image, but still put it before the div.

Comment: Can you up rate my answer please? :)

Answer (score 1):

position:absolute is in a screen context. To use position:absolute inside a div context, make the parent div as position:relative, so, his child with p:absolute will consider the top of his parent as orign.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your background image is either a .PNG and or a .GIF File Format. Both of these file types support transparency.